# Playing music using JFX in a Runnable Jar-file without batch-file

Tags: java, swing, batch-file, javafx-2

Lately I've been toying around with `JavaFX` and i've ran into a problem. I've been building a simple application to listen to my music-collection at home, from a remote computer, using sockets. The server is a console application and the client uses a `JFrame` window and plays mp3's using `JavaFX`.
The easiest way to use the client application on a external computer for me was to create a `Runnable Jar` File. The application runs fine, except for one thing: It won't play music. The only way i get it to work is by starting it using a simple .batch-file:

```
java -jar Test.jar
pause
```

The code of my example application is as follows:
(The problem is the same with this simple example, so i think the problem resides with the Runnable Jar-file and not my actual application).

```
import java.io.File;

import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;


public class SimpleAudioPlayer {

public SimpleAudioPlayer(){
    //Initialize JFXPanel to initialize JavaFX toolkit (workaround)
    JFXPanel jfx = new JFXPanel();

    Media mediaFile = new Media(new File("music/Song.mp3")
        .toURI().toString());
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(mediaFile);
    mp.play();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SimpleAudioPlayer();
}

}
```

How can i get the application to play music by simply executing the `Runnable jar` file?

Answer (score 0):

```
assoc .jar=jarfile
ftype jarfile=java.exe -jar %1 %*
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I executed your code, but now my program won't even start without a .batch file.

Comment: OK, i figured out what your code meant to do, but it wasn't the problem. My executable jar files are being executed by java.exe. But it seems to behave differently when exactly the same .jar is opened through a .batch-file.

Comment: this should associate .jar files to `java -jar` command.If they are executed directly with `java` could make a difference.Are you sure that your `PATH` variable points to the same `java.exe` as the one that your are associated with - it should be defined in the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft`